# How can i delete pnr by sabre api?

Tags: sabre, sabredav

I have create PNR using sabre rest api. Is there any way to cancel or delete this pnr through the api. I am using version v2.2.0 and mode "create".

Comment: Please clarify which elements exactly you want to cancel or delete. If there is already a ticket issue it requires additional steps then just booked segments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data your PNR has. There is no way to cancel a whole PNR, it will be purged by the system. You cancel segments instead. At the moment Sabre services that cancel segments can be used with SOAP and session tokens.