# Understanding Sabre itinerary segments cancellation

Tags: rest, api, soap, sabre

I could create PNR via Sabre REST API and now I want to cancel PNR. It seems there is no PNR cancellation API.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686398/how-can-i-delete-pnr-by-sabre-api), I will have to use `OTA_CancelLLSRQ` (Cancel Itinerary Segments) to cancel the segment.

Then, I decided to use `OTA_CancelLLSRQ` and this is a sample request data for `OTA_CancelLLSRQ` 
[documentation of Sabre](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/book/Cancel_Itinerary_Segments)

```xml
<OTA_CancelRQ Version="2.0.2">
    <Segment Type="entire"/>
</OTA_CancelRQ>
```

Here, I am a bit confused that there is no unique/reference ID or `Itinerary ID` in the request payload data.

How this is going to cancel a specific itinerary?

And also how can I cancel multiple itineraries at the same time?

Comment: perfect i already did it same as you done but a 500 internal server error returns

Comment: so can you tell me if it is worked with you ? and what was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation: [image: highlighted screenshot here]

When you call the GetResrvationRQ API first, the PNR becomes 'active' in your workspace so when you call OTA_CancelRQ, it applies to the PNR you pulled up. I do not believe it is possible to cancel an itinerary in a stateless mode.

Since you have to call the GetReservationRQ API on each PNR before you cancel, I do not think you can cancel more than one PNR at a time.

Comment: i already did this but i get 500 internal server error any advise ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link which provides details of the entire cancellation workflow:-
https://developer.sabre.com/cancel-booking

The internal logic executed by Cancel Booking is defined by the content on the Sabre PNR to be canceled. Because of this, the first step executed internally is to analyze the products in the Sabre PNR. This analysis creates a mapping of products, with the corresponding API, to be used for cancellation and creates a “segment sequence position” to “product id” mapping.

Hence before you make a call to cancel Itinerary Segments (OTA_CancelLLSRQ) API, you need to call Retrieve Itinerary (GetReservationRQ) API to set the context.